# JFrame - contents don't show correctly until window resized

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
Graphics2D g4 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g4.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g4.fillRect(180,500,45,-f);
g4.setFont (new Font("purisa", Font.PLAIN, 18));
g4.drawString("<$20", 180,520);
```

Hi,

The above is my code I am using to fill a rectangle. F is a variable which i've attained from a different class. It works fine when I specify the value, but when I use a variable it doesn't work.

When the program is opened:

[image]

When image is resized(works correctly):

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Where is that code hosted? Is it in a `paint` event handler?

Comment: I can think of any number of things that might cause this problem, but without some kind of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it would be waste of time on both our parts to even begin to list them...

Comment: Yeah it is, it's in 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had problems like this before. My guess is that the variable f is a member of a class that has not yet been initialized, the EDT paints before the variable is initialized and when you resize (cause repaint) the variable is now intialized and everything is painted correctly. This is sort of a racecondition.

A very easy to verify this guess would be to add a `println(f)` in the method to see what value f has the first time you are painting and what value f has on resize.

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I added a repaint() into the paint event handler rather than where I was creating the JFrame (in a different class) and it fixed it.

Comment: @user2761143: Don't call `repaint()` from `paintComponent()`.